# SvelteKit change port to different one

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit

I want to change port in production build of node-adapter. I use port 3000 internally for different service, so I need to change Svelte app to have port 3001.

**My Dockerfile:**

```
# Container setup ---------
FROM node:16-alpine as build

RUN mkdir /appbuild
COPY . /appbuild
WORKDIR /appbuild

# clean install all dependencies
RUN npm ci
# remove potential security issues
RUN npm audit fix
RUN npm run build

# Container setup ---------
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
# copy dependency list
COPY --from=build /appbuild/package*.json ./

# clean install dependencies, no devDependencies, no prepare script
RUN npm ci --production --ignore-scripts
# remove potential security issues
RUN npm audit fix
# copy built SvelteKit app to /app
COPY --from=build /appbuild/build ./
CMD ["node", "./index.js"]
```

I found that if I start app like `PORT=3001 node build` from root (after calling `npm run build`) it works, but for dockerfile, CMD must be provided and PORT cannot be passed.
How to change default port to another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)?

```
ENV PORT=3001
CMD ["node", "./index.js"]
```